# How to display the content in next page in flutter pdf?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I have data as List<Map<String,dynamic>>, in that I have route wise data, under route I have customer and under each customer there is products. I want to display route wise in page, some times route will have more customer, so I want to display that in next page after that another route.
Here is my code, if route has more customer it won't continue to next page

```
static Future<Uint8List> generate(
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> subscriptionDetail,
  Map<String, dynamic> merchantDetails,
  String storeName) async {
final pdf = pw.Document();

// Define page format (adjust as needed)
final pageFormat = PdfPageFormat.a4;

final font = await PdfGoogleFonts.nunitoExtraLight();
final ByteData _bytes =
    await rootBundle.load('assets/images/logo.png');
final Uint8List logobytes = _bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
// Define content height and maximum height
for (final entry in subscriptionDetail) {
  // Iterate through each key-value pair in the entry
  entry.forEach((route, customers) {
    // Add a new page for each route
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        build: (context) => pw.Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            buildHeader(merchantDetails, logobytes, storeName),
            pw.Text('Route: $route',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            pw.SizedBox(height: 6),
            for (final customer in customers.keys)
              pw.Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  pw.Text('Customer: $customer',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  pw.SizedBox(height: 6),
                  pw.Text('Products:',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [
                      for (final product in customers[customer]['products'])
                        pw.Wrap(
                          crossAxisAlignment: pw.WrapCrossAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            pw.Bullet(
                              text: product,
                              bulletSize: 5,
                              bulletMargin:
                                  const pw.EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  pw.SizedBox(height: 10),
                ],
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  });
}

return pdf.save();
```

}